# how to merge the result of two querys

Tags: java, mysql

i have a query like

```
SELECT class_id,student_id,title,location 
FROM class AS c 
INNER JOIN library AS l 
ON (l.student_id = c.student_id) 
group by class_id,student_id;
```

OUTPUT:

```
class_id   student_id    title   location
1           mac          smart    2ndfloor
1           john         smart     2ndfloor
1           charles      smart     2ndfloor
2           james        hard      1stfloor
```

Another query

```
SELECT school_id,class_id,s.title FROM school
```

output:

```
school_id class_id  title
1           1       school1
1           1       school1  
1           2       school1
```

i have to show the school record first then shows class in that school(i.e)

```
 school_id   class_id  title 
   1           NULL     school      //here school title and id
   1            1        2ndfloor   //here classes in that school
   2           NuLL      school2    //here next school title and id
   2            1        2ndfloor   //here classes in the next school
```

How can i achieve this,please some me it can be done in mysql itself or i need to use java List iterater to iterate it.i am using mysql database and java.

Comment: Handle presentation logic at the application level/presentation layer, e.g. a simple PHP loop - or, presumably, a smidge of java.

Comment: Combine both queryies or with loop codntions

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union in SQL Query to merge two results..

Orelse

In Code, you can go for some parent child gridviews.